# See close vote initiater, not just the close vote queue reviewers

Tags: support, close-reasons

I was the first, [close vote queue prompted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/close/80929) reviewer of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106122/mount-nfs-access-denied-by-server-while-mounting-on-ubuntu-machines) question. The original close reason was that it was cross posted on multiple sites.

Since there was no comment pointing to the "other" post. I did search via the profile for the OPs other site activities, did not find anything. Then realised the question was so old it would not be one of the first entries, looked again, still could not find the "other" post.

I would have tried to contact the person who allegedly found the cross post, whose name shows up as the first one if a post is put on hold/closed. I realised I don't know where to find that name until the post is closed. It is not in the review queue history (available for high rep).

Is there anywhere I could have found the name of the original close initiator, in order e.g. to ping the person on chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [Michael Hampton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20805/michael-hampton) in this case. Mods can see it as part of a post history view, but unfortunately I don't think there's a way for most users to see it until the post closes

Comment: In that case I won't look further. As he is not on chat, I'll leave it at that and not go hunting to ask him where the cross-post is.